# Why do Swift Argument Lables Matter for BLE Callback

Tags: swift, callback, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm working on my first Swift / BLE app and noticed that if the argument labels for the disconnect call back of the central manager don't match or an "_" is used the call back is never fired.  Being new to Swift am I was under the impression the labels are for readability only but apparently they are used to match function call backs.  Is that accurate?

This works:

```
 // Called when disconnected from BLE device
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?)
```

But removing or changing "didDisconnectPeripheral" to "didDisconnect" or "_" prevents the call back from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)` is an optional method of the `CBCentralManagerDelegate` protocol meaning that you won't receive an error if you don't implement it when conforming to the protocol. However, the argument labels are part of the function signature, so removing them makes the function different than the protocol method and hence it won't be called by the protocol if you declare it using the wrong argument labels/names.

You should however receive a warning stating that `Instance method 'centralManager(central:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)' of protocol 'CBCentralManagerDelegate'` if you change the function declaration to something that doesn't match the declaration in the protocol.

Comment: So labels are more than readability they are also part of and used for function signatures.  Thanks.  I did receive the warning and that helped me fix it.  I was curious how important labels are.

Comment: Yes, they have a meaning towards the type system as well, not just for the readers of your code.